# Grunt.js integratable pretty printer/formatter for HTML5

Tags: html, gruntjs, pretty-print

Are there any configurable HTML pretty printer / code formatter available, which I could integrate into Grunt.js?
The pretty printer/formatter should be configurable to meet our requirements.

some basic requirements:

- full HTML5 or partial HTML files
- file names with different endings (not only *.html or *.htm) are configurable
- identation size is configurable
- identation is done via spaces (not tabs)
- tabs are replaces with spaces

Comment: something like this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-prettify